# Change UITabBarItem badge background color under iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uitabbarcontroller, xcode5, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Is there a way to change the badge background color under iOS 7?

If not, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the default red background of the badge. Then, you cannot change the color directly. However, you can go ahead and use custom badges to fulfill your needs.

Here is a couple of easy-to-implement custom badges:

[MKNumberBadgeView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mknumberbadgeview)
[LKBadgeView](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/lkbadgeview)